# how to handle csrf only post request when no get request

Tags: node.js, express, csrf, csrf-token

I have a delete post route in my CSM. delete is not working because cross-site forgery detected, other routes working perfectly because there is one pair `GET POST` available. for the delete route, I have only one POST route. cms based on express.

could anyone fix this issue?  here is my code example

```
  <form action="/admin/category/delete/{{this.slug}}?newMethod=DELETE" method="post">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="{{csrfToken}}">
                                    <button data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Delete Folder"
                                        class="mx-1 btn btn-danger btn-sm float-left"><i
                                            class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
                                </form>
```

the csrfToken is not showing in the value

Comment: anyone here to give some idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this question answer will help anyone in the future. I just solve this problem with `axios`. it's very simple, pass the csrf token throw meta tag, and catch it with

```
const token = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content');



const deletebtn = document.querySelectorAll('.deleteBtn');
const token = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content');

function deletefunction() {
    const slug = $(this).data('slug');
    const config = {
        method: 'POST',
        url: `/admin/category/delete/${slug}`,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'CSRF-Token': token,
        },
    };
    axios(config).then((response) => {
        if (response) {
            window.location.href = response.request.responseURL;
        }
    });
}

if (deletebtn) {
    deletebtn.forEach((btn) => {
        btn.addEventListener('click', deletefunction, false);
    });
}
```

inside your controller

```
  delete: async (req, res) => {
            const deleteId = req.params.slug;
            await Category.destroy({ where: { slug: deleteId } });
            return res.redirect('/admin/category');
        },
```

inside html

```
<button data-slug="{{this.slug}}"class="deleteBtn mx-1 btn btn-danger btn-sm float-left"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
```